# Geom_label conditional change color text and padding

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I am creating a pie chart and I would like the color of the label text and padding to be white when the segment being labelled is filled with black. At the moment other labels follow the color of the segment labelled and I want to keep it so. The black filled segments also have black label text and can therefore not be seen, despite being there.

```r
ggplot(pigs2.proportions,
       aes(x="", y=comp_percent, fill = percent_class, width = 0.4)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  geom_label(
    aes(
      label = ifelse(comp_percent %% 1 != 0, sprintf("%.2f%%", comp_percent),
                     sprintf("%.0f%%", comp_percent))),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), 
    size = 4,
    label.padding = unit(0.25, "lines"),
    show.legend = FALSE) +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) +
  facet_wrap(~factor(source, levels = c("fish", "soy", "skim")), labeller = custom_labeller("source")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("low" = "black", "moderate" = "darkgray", "high" = "lightgray")) +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_blank(), # Hide labels on polar coordinate axis
    panel.grid = element_blank(),  # Remove grid lines
    panel.border = element_blank(),  # Remove round outline
    axis.text = element_blank(),  # Remove axis text
    axis.title = element_blank()  # Remove axis titles
  )
```

```r
structure(list(source = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L), levels = c("fish", "soy", "skim"), class = "factor"), 
    percent_class = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    2L), levels = c("low", "moderate", "high"), class = "factor"), 
    count = c(3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 5L), comp_percent = c(30, 
    20, 50, 10, 30, 60, 11.1111111111111, 33.3333333333333, 55.5555555555556
    ), pos = c(15, 10, 25, 35, 35, 80, 45.5555555555556, 66.6666666666667, 
    137.777777777778)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), groups = structure(list(
    percent_class = structure(1:3, levels = c("low", "moderate", 
    "high"), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(c(2L, 
    5L, 8L), c(3L, 6L, 9L), c(1L, 4L, 7L)), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L), .drop = TRUE))
```

[image: output from code]

Comment: You can assign `color = (percent_class == "low")` inside the `aes` of `geom_label`, then specify white and black as colors inside `scale_color_manual`

Comment: This solves the problem adequately (thank you!) but creates another problems where now the labels are not positioned inside each segment as before. Setting position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5) doesnt work either.

Comment: I don't understand why changing the color would make any difference Joe. Could you add a [mre] so I can actually run the code and fix it? `dput(pigs2.proportions)` should generate a reproducible data sample you can paste into your question.

Comment: reproducible data sample added!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @AllanCameron in the comments you could e.g. map the condition `percent_class == "low"` on the `color` aes and set your desired text colors using `scale_color_manual`. However, doing so changes the grouping of the data for `geom_label` and hence the stacking of the labels no longer aligns with the bars. To fix that you have to explicitly map `percent_class` on the `group` aes.

```r
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(
  pigs2.proportions,
  aes(x = "", y = comp_percent, fill = percent_class, width = 0.4)
) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
  facet_wrap(
    ~ factor(source, levels = c("fish", "soy", "skim")),
    # labeller = custom_labeller("source")
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("low" = "black", "moderate" = "darkgray", "high" = "lightgray")
  ) +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_blank(), # Hide labels on polar coordinate axis
    panel.grid = element_blank(), # Remove grid lines
    panel.border = element_blank(), # Remove round outline
    axis.text = element_blank(), # Remove axis text
    axis.title = element_blank() # Remove axis titles
  )

p +
  geom_label(
    aes(
      label = ifelse(comp_percent %% 1 != 0,
        sprintf("%.2f%%", comp_percent),
        sprintf("%.0f%%", comp_percent)
      ),
      color = percent_class == "low",
      group = percent_class
    ),
    position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
    size = 4,
    label.padding = unit(0.25, "lines"),
    show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "white"))
```

[image]

A second option would be to use `after_scale` to conditionally set the `color` based on the value of `fill` like so:

```r
p +
  geom_label(
    aes(
      label = ifelse(comp_percent %% 1 != 0,
        sprintf("%.2f%%", comp_percent),
        sprintf("%.0f%%", comp_percent)
      ),
      color = after_scale(
        ifelse(fill == "black", "white", "black")
      )
    ),
    position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
    size = 4,
    label.padding = unit(0.25, "lines"),
    show.legend = FALSE
  )
```

[image]